# How to put an image in this table

Tags: php, html, css

im having a problem and i can't seem to put an image icon on my delete and edit button i've put a div class and styled it in my css but still the image doesn't show.what might be wrong here?

HTML

```
             <?php 
                 $this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Contact Number","Number of Guest","Date of Arrival","Time","Pickup Location","Package","Other Request","Delete Record","Edit Record");
                 $qry = $this->db->like('name',$search_key)->order_by('date')->get('booking');
                 if ($qry->num_rows > 0) {
                 foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
              $this->table->add_row(anchor('site/print_records/'.$row->id, $row->name, 'target="_blank"'),$row->nationality,$row->contactnum,$row->number_of_guest,$row->date,$row->time,$row->pickup,$row->package,$row->request,anchor('site/delete/'.$row->id, "<div class='deleteico'></div>),anchor('site/update/'.$row->id, "<div class='editico'></div>));
               }
               }
            else{
          echo "No records found!";
            }

              echo $this->table->generate();

            ?>
```

CSS

```
#deleteico{
         background-image: url('../pictures/delete_icon.png');
     }
 #editico{
         background-image: url('../pictures/edit_icon.png');
      }
```

Comment: give it some dimensions

Comment: you have given class in php and in css you are calling id. check that <div class='editico'></div> and in css it is #editco, it has to .editco

Answer (score 2):

You are using `class` in your code and are applying the css to an `id` selector.

If you want to use classes, change your css to the following:

```
.deleteico{
    background-image: url('../pictures/delete_icon.png');
}
.editico{
    background-image: url('../pictures/edit_icon.png');
}
```

`#` is used to select IDs, and `.` is used for classes.

Note: and as @skip405 has mentioned as well, you will need to set a `width` and `height` in your css or the div will be 0x0 big and thus not show anything.

Comment: [So how is this answer different from this one ?? An already and much before answer to this question ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473835/how-to-put-an-image-in-this-table/22473893#22473893)

Comment: it manages to show the image but its not showing it whole..i tried to resize it but it still shows half or 1/4 of it..damn its hard to explain lol..hope you understand

Comment: @NathanLee, I personally voted for this answer instead of yours for two reasons: a) it suggests using classes, not id's (id's are way worse in CSS) b) it does not suggest inserting unneeded `&nbsp;`. I guess that's how it's a) different and b) better

Comment: @NathanLee We wrote our answer at pretty much the same time. I didn't see yours before I submitted mine.

Comment: 1. OP has an id, but he has mistakenly given classes, so I need to correct his markup rather than change his style. So id is for that reason. 2. `&nbsp` doesn't substantially affect on OP, as he has a background image, so inserting it and smartly using it, would save him lines of code, as he has wants this as a blank div. I hope my point is justified. - @skip405

Comment: That is fine - @DarkAshelin . My point was to know the differentiation and if there was not big one, I would have respected you mentioning the reference to my answer. It happens with me all the time, just seconds before I press submit, a new one with my resembled one gets printed and that is obvious.

Comment: @NathanLee About the div/class thing, it seems to me that he will definitely be using the same icons more than once on the same page, as the content is printed on a loop. So probably he will need both divs (with icon background) in each row.

Comment: Yes. It will.- @DarkAshelin

Comment: @NathanLee so it should be a class.

Comment: But point is, OP has not specified anything related to loop. I agreed to what you mention, but that is not necessarily what the OP is intending to use for. - @DarkAshelin

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space inside your brakets:

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `width` and `height` of the `background-image` to the `#deleteico` and `#editico` ids. Then add `&nbsp;` to them and change it to `id` from `class` in your code.

**For instance,**

```
    <div id='deleteico'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id='editico'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Hope this helps.